# Cannot resolve symbol 'MoEInitializer'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, moengage

I'm trying to install MoEngage SDK on my flutter app. I need to add native code to my project according to the docs. I'm getting this import error in the SampleApplication.java file

[image: This is the error]

I've added the dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "androidx.core:core:1.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.2.0"
    implementation "com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:10.6.00"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add dependency at flutter `pubspec.yaml` file

```
dependencies:
    moengage_flutter: $lastestVersion
```

Also don't forget to run `flutter pub get`

as the documentations said [here](https://developers.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404304782356-SDK-Installation)